Why doesn't Neovim version number follows semantic versioning rules?
Some developers are afraid to use the first number in the semantic version for unknown reasons.
What is the sense to keep the major number always at 0? For what feature needs?
It must be increased when a new release contains breaking changes.
Semantic version: major.minor.patch.
Neovim version: 0.major.minor.
What will they do when they need to release a patch?
According to my experience, about 20% of software developers, mainly from the Unix world, break semversion standard and always keeps the first number at 0. This is some mind corruption.

You should ask this on the Neovim issue tracker not here

You're probably referring to semantic versioning. It's not a standard, more like a reasonable suggestion. It's not the only instance where reasonable and Neovim don't go together very well. I voted to close as opinion-based.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Neovim plans to go for version 1.0 in April 2026.
Here is the 1.0 milestone tracker.
The current version is still considered somehow beta.

They're still changing and experimenting with the APIs, so it seems appropriate at least...
